# Using UPDATE with MERGE WHEN NOT MATCHED

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

If I'm updating from a query like below. I can wrap the t2.co1 in a COALESCE function to provide an alternative value for rows not found in the source query.

```
    UPDATE
        t1
    SET
        t1.col1 = COALESCE(t2.col1,0)
    FROM
        table AS t1
    LEFT JOIN
        other_table AS t2
    ON
        t1.id = t2.id
```

I recently discovered the MERGE statement - but then found that you can't do an UPDATE on WHEN NOT MATCHED clauses. Is there a way to do this with MERGE or should I stick to using above?

Comment: No you can't use Merge here. Merge performs insert, update, or delete operations on a target table based on the results of a join with a source table.

Comment: Is there anything your existing query doesn't do that you want it to?  If not, then use what you have.  `MERGE` is for fairly complicated processes where you're doing several things at once.  For your query, the only thing I'd suggest is adding `WHERE t1.col1 <> COALESCE(t2.col1,0) OR t1.col IS NULL` so you're only updating where you need to update.

Answer (score 4):

As for me I like to use `MERGE`, but I agree that it has no sense for your particular simple case. But if we take into consideration that this is simplified example we can solve this task with `MERGE`. In your case you need to set value of `col1` to 0 in target table (`@table`) when it has no match in source table (`@other_table`). Here we are:

```
-- Setting up test tables and data
DECLARE @table TABLE (
     id     INT
    ,col1   INT
)
INSERT INTO @table (id, col1) VALUES (1, 101)
INSERT INTO @table (id, col1) VALUES (2, 102)
INSERT INTO @table (id, col1) VALUES (3, 103)
INSERT INTO @table (id, col1) VALUES (4, 104)

-- Target table before update
SELECT * FROM @table

DECLARE @other_table TABLE (
     id     INT
    ,col1   INT
)
INSERT INTO @other_table (id, col1) VALUES (1, 201)
INSERT INTO @other_table (id, col1) VALUES (2, 202)
INSERT INTO @other_table (id, col1) VALUES (3, 203)

-- Merging target and source tables
MERGE INTO @table AS t1
   USING @other_table AS t2
        ON  t1.id = t2.id

WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE
      SET   col1 = t2.col1

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
THEN
   UPDATE
      SET   col1 = 0
;

-- Target table after update using merge
SELECT * FROM @table
```

Resume - use `MERGE` when you really need *merge*, use `UPDATE` when you need only *update*.

Answer (score -3):

Simple example of merge in SQL SERVER

```
CREATE TABLE #targetTable(id int,name varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE #sourceTable(id int,name varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #sourceTable values(1,'John');
INSERT INTO #sourceTable values(1,'Albrt');
INSERT INTO #sourceTable values(1,'Roy');

MERGE #targetTable AS [target]
USING #sourceTable AS [source]
ON [target].id = [source].id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (id, Name)
VALUES (source.id, source.Name);

select * from #targetTable as T
drop table #targetTable
drop table #sourceTable
```